# How to prevent duplicated results in this MySQL JOIN?

Tags: mysql, join

I'm trying to show a list of expenses of a specific user.

Each expense can have a type.

Expenses, users, and types are all in different tables.

When I try to show the list using JOIN, I get duplicated values:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
          gastos.gastoID, 
          gastos.userID, 
          tiposPago.tipoPago AS tipo
FROM      gastos
LEFT JOIN tiposPagoGastos
ON        gastos.userID = tiposPagoGastos.userID
LEFT JOIN tiposPago
ON        tiposPagoGastos.tiposPagoID = tiposPago.tiposPagoID
WHERE     gastos.userID = 8
```

This is my Expense table:

```
CREATE TABLE gastos(
    gastoID int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,
    userID int not null,
    fecha char(25) null COMMENT 'en formato timestamp',
    monto int(10) null,
    detalles text null
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

This is my payment type table

```
CREATE TABLE tiposPago(
    tiposPagoID int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,
    tipoPago varchar(300) null,
    userID int not null,
    detalles text null
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

This is the table that join the payment types and the expenses

```
CREATE TABLE tiposPagoGastos(
    tiposPagoGastosID int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,
    gastoID int not null,
    tiposPagoID int not null,
    userID int not null
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

There are two types of expenses for this user: "American Express" and "Visa"

**This is the result I expect:**

```
gastoID -- userID -- tipo   
64 ------- 8  ------ American Express
65 ------- 8  ------ Visa
```

This is the result I get:

```
gastoID -- userID -- tipo   
64 ------- 8  ------ American Express
65 ------- 8  ------ American Express
64 ------- 8  ------ Visa
65 ------- 8  ------ Visa
```

If I add to the query: `GROUP BY gastos.gastoID`, this is the result I get:

```
gastoID -- userID -- tipo   
64 ------- 8  ------ American Express
65 ------- 8  ------ American Express
```

**This last result is incorrect because the gastoID "65" should be VISA.**

### The input information is this:

**tiposPago table**

```
tiposPagoID     tipoPago           userID   detalles
1               VISA                8       banco Galicia
2               American Express    8       Santander
```

**tiposPagoGastos table**

```
gastoID     userID  tiposPagoID
64          8         2
65          8         1
```

How to get the right list without duplicated results?

Comment: In your current result, there are no duplicates. gastoID is different for the two rows. You need to show sample input data based on which you expected those results.

Comment: change LEFT JOIN to INNER JOIN

Comment: @GurwinderSingh I've updated the question to clarify it. The sample data that I have is the one that I've shown (the other results I've deleted them): gastoID 64 should have American Express type, and gastoID 65 should be Visa, and the result shown is incorrect.

Comment: @PeterKalef'DidiSoft I still get the wrong results with INNER JOIN.

Comment: @Rosamunda - the given is expected result and actual results, **not** input data.

Comment: @PeterKalef'DidiSoft Thanks for the clarification, I've updated the question.

Comment: By the way, I would appreciate a comment on why the downvote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This worked, I was doing the JOIN using the wrong fields (just in case it helps someone, some day, I post the answer):**

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
          gastos.gastoID, 
          gastos.userID,
          tiposPagoGastos.tiposPagoID,
          tiposPago.tipoPago
FROM      gastos
LEFT JOIN tiposPagoGastos
ON gastos.gastoID = tiposPagoGastos.gastoID
LEFT JOIN tiposPago
ON tiposPagoGastos.tiposPagoID = tiposPago.tiposPagoID
WHERE     gastos.userID = 8
```